# Making my asynchronous code synchronous with setTimeout. Do I need promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, request, promise

I'm building a data scraper for a particular website. Because I want to only make a request every 10 seconds, I've set it up as a setTimeout loop that takes a url as a parameter from an array of urls that I manually input. In the callback it requests this url and parses the response, pushing the data into a new array structured so that it can ultimately be converted into a csv. I'll paste the full code below along with my dependancies.

The issue is that approximately 1 in 5 of these requests returns as undefined. I thought that the timeout function would take care of this and the program would run synchronously I was clearly wrong. Researching this I've found that a lot of people use a promises dependency to order asynchronous requests. My question here: is that necessary? Or can I tweak my callback/setTimeout so that it works without adding another dependency?

**Edit** Since it wasn't clear I'm copying in here exactly what I want this app to do:
I want the program to take a request, return a json string, parse that json string for data, add that data to an array, and export that array as a csv. I want to loop this functionality so it can do this for a long list of URLs but I want it to ONLY make 1 request at a time and wait to iterate to the next request until the required data has been collected from the initial response. And I want to only send a request every 10 seconds.

Here is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var app     = express();

var arr = [];

var url = //A bunch of urls that I'm leaving out to conserve space


i = 0;
function timeout() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        request(url[i], function(error, response, html){     
            if(error){
                console.log(error);
            } else {

                var $ = cheerio.load(html);

                var company, industry, size, website, type;

                var inArr = [];
                $('div .image-wrapper img').filter(function(){
                    var data = $(this);
                     company = data.attr('alt');
                     inArr.push("\"" + company + "\"");
               })

                 $('.industry p').filter(function(){
                     var data = $(this);            
                     industry = data.text();  
                     inArr.push("\"" + industry + "\"");
                })

                 $('.company-size p').filter(function(){
                     var data = $(this);                 
                     size = data.text();
                     inArr.push("\"" + size + "\"");
                })

                 $('.website p a').filter(function(){
                     var data = $(this);                 
                     website = data.text();
                     inArr.push("\"" + website + "\"");
                })

                 $('.type p').filter(function(){
                     var data = $(this);                 
                     type = data.text();
                     inArr.push("\"" + type + "\"");
                })


                arr.push(inArr);
                console.log("I just sourced data for " + company);

                if (i === url.length - 1) {
                    clearTimeout(timeout);
                    console.log("All done!")
                    var csvContent;
                    arr.forEach(function(infoArray, index){

                       dataString = infoArray.join(",");
                       csvContent += index < arr.length ? dataString+ "\n" : dataString;

                    });
                    fs.writeFile('output.csv', csvContent, function(err){
                        console.log('File successfully written! - Check your project directory for the output.csv file');
                    });

                } else {
                    i++;
                    timeout();                  
                }
            }

        });
    }, 10000);

};


timeout();
```

Comment: _"The issue is that approximately 1 in 5 of these requests returns as undefined."_ What is expected result of `clearTimeout(timeout);` ? `setTimeout` within `timeout` function is not declared intially or later set as `timeout` variable ? `timeout` is defined only as a function at `js` at Question

Comment: What is the real question here?  Are you just trying to run a nunber of `request()` operations, one after the other?  If so, guessing how long they will take with `setTimeout()` is a bad design.  You should write actual code that will sequence the operations.  But first, please clarify what the REAL problem is here, not what the problem is with your `setTimeout()` solution.  We can only help you find the best solution to your problem if you explain the actual problem, not only your attempt at a solution.

Comment: `clearTimeout(timeout);` makes NO sense at all for a bunch of reasons.  `timeout` is a function in your code, not a timer ID.  `clearTimeout()` works on the return value from a call to `setTimeout()`. as in `var timer = setTimeout(f, t);   clearTimeout(timer);`.  Further the logic of using `clearTimeout()` when you're already executing the result of the `setTimeout()` makes no sense.  The timer has already fired.

Comment: @jfriend00 I appreciate the response and I apologize if I wasn't clear. setTimeout is not at all essential to my design. I wanted a way to make sure that a request would only be sent every 10 seconds and it seemed like the best way.

Comment: Please edit your question to say that you want to send one request every ten seconds, but presumably not before the previous request has finished.

Comment: @jfriend00 What I want the program to do take a request, return a json string, parse that json string for data, add that data to an array, and export that array as a csv. I want to loop this functionality so it can do this for a long list of URLs but I want it to ONLY make 1 request at a time and wait to iterate to the next request until the required data has been collected from the initial response. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, it is starting to make sense and I have provided an answer to do that.  I'm asking you to put that explanation of the actual problem into your question above so people reading your question see that description of the problem without having to read every single comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the real problem here is that you want to send one request after another, but no sooner than 10 seconds apart, then you can do that like this by making a little wrapper function that tells you when it's time for the next call:

```
var request = require('request');

function requestNext(url, callback, delay, nextCallback) {
    var start = Date.now();
    request(url, function(error, response, html) {
        callback(error, response, html);
        var elapsed = Date.now() - start;
        var wait = Math.max(delay - elapsed, 0);
        // schedule next call to request()
        setTimeout(nextCallback, wait);
    });
}
```

Then, you can just call requestNext() specifying the delay time and a second callback that will tell you when to make the next call.

Then, in your particularly circumstance, you could use that with a repeat function like this:

```
function getURLs(urls, delay, processCallback, doneCallback) {
    var index = 0;
    var data = [];

    function next() {
        if (index < urls.length) {
            requestNext(urls[index++], function(err, response, html) {
                // need to decide what you want do for error handling here
                // continue? stop further processing?
                data.push(processCallback(err, response, html));
            }, delay, next);
        } else {
            doneCallback(null, data);
        }
    }
    next();
}

getURLs(urlArray, 10000, processResult, function(err, dataArray) {
   if (!err) {
       // results are in dataArray
   }
});
```

Then, put your logic to process a URL in a function named processResult that looks like this:

```
function processResult(err, response, html) {
    // your code to process a page here
    // return the final result as a return value and it will be collected for you
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your patience, and your help. After a bit of fiddling and personalization this solution worked for me. I would upvote your answer but the act of posting this question has caused people to downvote me.

Comment: Frankly, this is the reason myself and a lot of people I know who are learning to code avoid Stack Overflow. I researched my question, I tried to figure out what was wrong- spent hours on it in fact. And when you asked me to clarify I clarified. This is supposed to be a place for people to help each other - not reject and exclude. But that's most of what I see in every question I click into, exclusion. Again, I really appreciate your help jfriend. Your code and explanation were both flawless. But the next time I have a question, I'll probably go somewhere else.

Comment: @AaronHill - You can accept this answer by checking the green checkmark to the left of that answer.  I didn't downvote you, but you can get downvotes on questions if they aren't entirely clear and if you don't immediately respond to questions by editing your question.  If I recall, it took awhile before you clarified your question and one downvote is no big deal.  The community here doesn't tolerate questions that don't meet the guidelines.  With a little practice, you can get good at writing clear questions the first time or responding immediately if unclear.

Comment: @AaronHill - Also, don't take it so hard if you get an occasional downvote. It's no big deal. The downvoting system that penalizes unclear or off-topic questions and the downvoting and upvoting system on answers is what makes this one of the best places on the internet for answers. Other places that have no feedback system like this are literally full of garbage and wrong answers and if you don't already know the answer you may not know which is which. In general, bad answers here are downvoted by people who know.  And, good answers are usually upvoted, sometimes a lot.  That's the value here.

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting `js` to declare a variable which references `setTimeout` . At `js` at Question, `clearTimeout()` is called with `timeout` as parameter, though `timeout` is a function , not a reference to the `setTimeout` called within `timeout()` . At `js` below `t` is declared as variable outside of `timeout` function, set to reference for `setTimeout` within `timeout()` call.

See [WindowTimers.setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(func, [delay, param1, param2, ...]);
> var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(code, [delay]);
> ```

```js
var arr = [];

var url = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]; 

var i = 0;

var t = null;

function timeout() {
  t = setTimeout(function() {
    (function() {
        var inArr = [];
        inArr.push(i)
        arr.push(inArr);
        console.log("I just sourced data for " + i, t);
        if (i === url.length - 1) {
          clearTimeout(t);
          console.log("All done!", i, url.length - 1, arr)
        } else {
          i++;
          timeout();
        }
    }());
  }, 1000); // reduced duration to `1000` for stacksnippets
};

timeout();
```